# Want to read file in key value form in java

Tags: java

I need to read a file in java and file is in below format:

```
type=abc, name=xyz, value=abc123
type=aaa, name=zzz, value=abc456
type=bbb, name=ccc, value=abc001
```

So I want read this file as a key value pair, so what would be the best way to read this file?

Please note that this not the properties file.

Comment: Split by ",", then split by "="

Comment: Read file line by line and use regex to extract necessary data.

Comment: @amuser Did any of the answers below answer your question? If so, mark one as correct by clicking the check box. If not, let us know what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read in the file line by line, and then use string.split("separator") to split the string into each part.

A layout of an algorithm would be as follows:

- Read in file line by line
- Split each line by a comma, which gives you an array of each key value pair
- Split each element in the aforementioned array by a "=", giving you an array with two element, the first being the key, the second being the value.

Code example

```
String s = "... content read in from file ..."
String[] pairs = s.split(","); // This would split it into sections divided by the comma, resulting in an array of Strings with elements such as "type=abc"

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (String string : pairs) {
    String[] keyValue = string.split("="); // Split on the "=" of an element such as "type=abc", resulting in a String array of two elements, "type" and "abc"
    map.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]); // Store those values however you'd like
};
```

Comment: Since there is a space after the comma, might want to include some `trim()` calls as well